# How do I set up Apache HTTPD as a proxy service for HTTPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, httpd, cache

I am trying to set up a proxy service for a packaging service (npm and bower.io) and I’d like to cache the packages locally.

My Apache configuration:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:10010
Listen 127.0.0.1:10011

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:10011>

ProxyRequests On

SSLEngine On
ServerName 127.0.0.1:10011

SSLProtocol All

SSLCertificateFile /opt/npm-cache/certs/npmcache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/npm-cache/certs/npmcache.key

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

CacheRoot /opt/npm-cache/data/ssl
CacheEnable disk /
CacheDirLevels 5
CacheDirLength 3
CacheDefaultExpire 2628000 

ErrorLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/ssl-error.log
CustomLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/ssl-custom.log common
TransferLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/ssl-transfer.log

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:10010>

ServerName 127.0.0.1:10010

ProxyRequests On

CacheRoot /opt/npm-cache/data/non-ssl
CacheEnable disk /
CacheDirLevels 5
CacheDirLength 3
CacheDefaultExpire 2628000 

ErrorLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/error.log
CustomLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/custom.log common
TransferLog /opt/npm-cache/logs/transfer.log

</VirtualHost>
```

This does not work. The problem I see in the logs:

```
[Mon Jan 27 14:15:01 2014] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] (70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed.
[Mon Jan 27 14:15:01 2014] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] Connection closed to child 4 with standard shutdown (server 127.0.0.1:10011)
```

The certificates for my server are self-signed.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you use nginx for that purpose as it's a better caching server.

The config for nginx is something like this:

```
server {
listen   443;
server_name  www.npmpackages.com;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/npmpackages-ssl.access.log;

ssl  on;
ssl_certificate     ssl/npmpackages_com.bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key ssl/npmpackages_com.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:+SSLv3:-EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://www.npmpackages.com;
    proxy_cache on;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: proxy_pass is not https?